# Casting string to 'unit' object in Python

Tags: python, string, casting, units-of-measurement

*In this question "unit(s)" refers to "unit(s) of measure" used in physical quantities.*

I want to safely parse an untrusted user input string containing physical quantities (e.g. '23 kg'). I'd like to use one of the packages available for Python (like *Unum* or *Quantities*), because they take care of conversions between units, simplification of units contained in mathematical expression, reduction to base units, but I could not find a way to convert a string to an object (of the aforementioned packages) other than using `eval()`, which seems unsafe.

For example, assuming that `kg` and `cm` are bound to *Unum* package objects and refer to the kilogram and centimetre units, I need a function capable of returning an *Unum* package object from a string, something like:

`cast_to_unit("100 kg/cm")`

or

`"100 kg/cm".asUnit()`

1. Is there a way to obtain such functionality from one the
   mentioned packages? And if not,
2. Is there a way to safely use
   `eval()`? And if not,
3. Is there any other package (even not in
   Python) having such functionality?

Comment: What's a `Unit` and why should it take a string as argument?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be adequately explained, IMHO. Wouldn't cast to unit need to know what units the original quantity is in, and the desired units of the output, and be given a quantity as a float instead of a string? Perhaps if you give a concrete example instead of 'm', that would help.

Comment: @Jonathan Hartley  This conversion cases are already well managed by the packages I mentioned, Unum and Quantities, but in such packages I couldn't find a way to obtain an object from a string.

Comment: @mmj then it'd a question for the authors of the package, surely?

Comment: This is so simple to code up yourself, I certainly wouldn't make it a prerequisite for choosing a package.

Comment: @kindall Are you sure is so simple to code a complete unit managing package? Why such packages (many kb long) exist then?

Comment: I still don't understand. Does "cast_to_unit('100*kg')" mean you want to cast 100kg to some other unit? What other unit?

Comment: @JonathanHartley -- I think it means that OP wants to take the string `'100*kg'` and convert it to a unit object of type `kg` with a value of `100`.

Comment: @Jonathan Hartley No, it means I want to cast a string to a 'unit' object.

Comment: No, it's not simple to code a complete units package, but the process of parsing a string and passing it to whatever units package you want is straightforward. It would take about ten minutes to code that up, and I'm being conservative. I surely wouldn't choose a units package based on whether it provided that for me or not.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932032/convert-a-string-to-python-quantity/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a quick look at `Unum`'s [documentation](http://home.scarlet.be/be052320/docs.html), it appears that you should be able to do something like this with [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
from unum.units import * # Load a number of common units.
distance = 100*m
time = eval('9.683*s')
speed = distance / time
print(speed)
```

If you do this though, make sure that you read the documentation on `eval` and how you can pass local and global mappings in order to restrict the namespace access to make it safer -- especially if you ever plan on releasing this code to the outside world.  You'll probably also want to check the strings for underscores (`_`) and not allow those to be passed to `eval`.

---

As noted by kindall, importing `*` is usually not good style.  Here's a slightly more safe alternative which avoids importing from `*`:

```
import unum.units
safe_dict = dict((x,y) for x,y in unum.units.__dict__.items() if '__' not in x)
safe_dict['__builtins__'] = None

def convert(s):
    if '__' in s:
       raise ValueError("Won't do this with underscores...it's unsafe")
    return eval(s,safe_dict)
```

Note that I cut out the `__` methods as advocated in this [post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: The `*` import is a bad idea because it makes all the units global names and you can't use those names for variables. Better to do `import unum.units` and then pass `vars(unum.units)` to `eval` as the global variables.

Comment: @kindall -- This was copied more or less directly from Unum's documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `eval()` on user input for well known safety reasons.

Comment: No doubt a correct answer with quoted docs, but can't +1 so, does +0 count?

Comment: @mmj then why don't you chose another package or "roll your own", given those reasons?

Comment: That means Unum's documentation in bad, not that wildcard imports are good.  :-)

Comment: @Jon Clements  In fact I'm (just) asking if such code already exists.

Comment: @kindall -- I've updated.  The reason for the wildcard import in the first version is that it's necessary to bring 's' into the namespace that `eval` is using (without complicating what I was passing to `eval`).  It's mostly for demonstration purposes to show how `eval` works.  I've added a better (safer) version which also doesn't use a wildcard import, but it's slightly more complex ... Hopefully it's a complete answer now ...

Comment: @kindall I think migilson knows how imports work by now - we're discussing the OP's use case...

Comment: I basically adopted your answer, I just added the copying of `safe_dict` passed to `eval()` cause I noted that otherwise `safe_dict` is *polluted* by `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: this is not a definitive answer. Please treat it as an example of how to build something similar to what you asked for. It is really a better idea to use `Unum` module, unless it does not fit your needs.

You can write something yourself, overloading the operators like that:

```py
>>> class Unit(object):
    def __init__(self, unit_name):
        self.unit_name = unit_name
        self.unit_qty = 1
    def __div__(self, other):
        result = self.__class__(self.unit_name)
        result.unit_qty = self.unit_qty / other
        return result
    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        result = self.__class__(self.unit_name)
        result.unit_qty = other / self.unit_qty
        return result
    def __mul__(self, other):
        result = self.__class__(self.unit_name)
        result.unit_qty = self.unit_qty * other
        return result
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.unit_qty, self.unit_name)


>>> kg = Unit('kg')
>>> 100 * kg
100 kg
>>> 100 * 10 * kg
1000 kg
>>> (10 * 20 * kg) / 2
100 kg
```

Then you could use `eval()` to evaluate expressions (like "`100*kg`"), but be careful about it. Probably this should help you get rid of some of the problems:

```py
eval('100*kg', {'__builtins__': {}, 'kg': Unit('kg')})
```

Comment: Do you think that if I used such explicit definition of `globals` and `locals` I would avoid all safety issues related to `eval()`? This workaround could solve my problem too.

Comment: @mmj: Maybe, but I would not bet on it. My initial tests did not find any issue, but that does not mean there isn't _any_.