# Convert a string to python quantity

Tags: python

In one of my projects I'm using the quantities package to represent physical quantities. These quantities have to be stored in the metadata of pngs where they must be readable by other programs and by my own program. Thus, the quantities must be stored as string (requirement of png metadata) and it would be best to store it in a human-readable format.

While the package quantities provides conversation from quantities to string, there seems to be no readily available method to parse these strings back to a quantity. The strings generated by the quantities package are, e.g.,

```
1.3 nm
[1.4 3.1415 5.2] kg/m**2
```

Is there an easy way to convert these strings back to a quantities.Quantity?

Comment: When looking for answers to the above question I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611851/converting-string-to-physical-quantity-object-in-python) question, which probably is the same thing but unfortunately the question is closed and the answers are not fitting all my needs.

Comment: There's very little point to a self-answered question so vague that: 1. Anyone else with a similar problem would struggle to find it; and 2. Nobody else could answer even if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand your point @jonrsharpe. When I had this problem, I've been searching stackoverflow and I came across the question mentioned in my comment. Unfortunately, the answers there have not been satisfying, so I came up with my own solution. I then wanted to share this solution with the one asking the original question b/c I thought other people may have the same problem. As the original question was closed, I had to ask a new question to share the solution. What should I've done differently?

Comment: For starters, the PNG is irrelevant. Next, you don't actually show the string you're trying to parse, nor explain how it ended up in that format. Finally, your answer just boils down to *"separate number and units, parse number to float and pass float and units to initialise"*, and that seems trivial enough to not warrant this effort.

Comment: The package `pint` could suit your needs: http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/

Comment: @mmj My program is only part of a bigger project and I have to use quantities. But at first glance, pint looks very interesting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the feedback. I tried to give some more information. Of course, once you know the solution, it is fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code and I think it should work for most cases.

```
import quantities as pq
import numpy as np

def str2pq(s):
    p1 = s.find('[')
    if p1 < 0:
        sq, su = s.split()
        return pq.Quantity(float(sq), su)
    else:
        p2 = s.find(']')
        ss = s[p1+1:p2-1]
        return pq.Quantity(np.array(list(map(float, ss.split()))), s[p2+1:])

q = [pq.Quantity(10, 'nm'), pq.Quantity(1.0, pq.kilogram/pq.meter**2), pq.Quantity(np.array([1.2, 3.4]), pq.kilohertz)]
qs = list(map(str, q))
qret = list(map(str2pq, qs))
print(q)
print(qret)
```